# z-order of plot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx to have a shared x-axis in matplotlib for both . I am being unable to order the plots using zorder. What I want is to plot the line graphs with ax1 to be on the front and bar grpah with ax2 to be behind it.

I know there is a related question to it, but it actually didn't help much. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639967/z-order-across-axes-when-using-matplotlibs-twinx)

[Link of data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DD8VnzwIsmL-ayaP3bEAyYyb3ZXlIokH/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataFrame=pd.read_csv("NEM.csv",sep=',')
dataFrame['ratio']=dataFrame['Expert']/dataFrame['Novice']


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax1.set_title('N-E Analysis')
xticklabels=dataFrame['Task'].tolist()

ax1.plot('Novice', data=dataFrame, marker='', color='dodgerblue', linewidth=2,label='Novice',zorder=3)
ax1.plot('Expert', data=dataFrame, marker='', color='darkorange', linewidth=2,label='Expert',zorder=2)

plt.ylim(0,120)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.bar('Task','ratio', data=dataFrame, color='gray',width=0.35,label='NE',zorder=0)


ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)


ax1.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, rotation = 45, ha="right")
ax1.yaxis.grid()
ax1.tick_params(left='off',bottom='off')
ax2.tick_params(right='off')
plt.ylim(0,12)

h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
p=ax1.legend(h2+h1, l2+l1, loc=2,frameon=False)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
ax1.set_zorder(2)
ax2.set_zorder(1)
ax1.patch.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me! Can you elaborate why was it not showing that way?

Comment: It simply sets the canvas of the plot invisible.